# How to handle different suffix in i18next for agglutinative languages (eg. Turkish, Japanese, etc.)

Tags: localization, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am trying to add Turkish support in my product. Turkish is agglutinative language. Which means that it tends to express concepts in complex words consisting of many elements, rather than by inflection or by using isolated elements.
Currently we have created keys for `i18next` like following:
`tr/resourceExample.json`

```
{
    "comment":"Yorum",
    "comment_plural":"Yorumlar",
    "select_label":"{{label}} seç"
}
```

Whenever we want to add a sentence like `"Select comments"` we use

```
t("resourceExample:select_label",{label:t("resourceExample:comment_plural")})
```

Now this works properly for languages like English or Spanish. But for Turkish, the suffix of `comment` changes if the word is used with verb.

For example, our currently key structure will give output for Turkish following:

> Yorumlar seç

But the actual expected result for Turkish is:

> Yorumları seç

The reason behind keeping this structure is that we didn't want to create new keys for `select_label` because `Select something` is used in many places where `something` can be replaced by many different words.

So, my question is that is there any functionality in `i18next` which can help in this situation?

Comment: I can shamelessly plug my little library here if you want to add some basic suffixes to Turkish nouns: [Afiixi](https://canpacis.github.io/affixi/). But other than that if you want consistent results, you need different libraries for each agglutinative language if you don't want to do it with machine learning (in my humble opinion, I may be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you can add custom format function.

```
i18next.services.formatter.add('objectify', (value, lng, options) => {
    if(lng=='tr'){
        //add suffix or any decorations here
        value=value+"ı";
    }
    return value
})
```

Read more at [i18next Docs](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting#adding-custom-format-function)